# Shift grouped series in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a grouped series that I'd like to shift and add to a DF. The grouped series looks like:

```
month  day  hour_dep  origin
1      1    5         LGA       1
            6         EWR       4
                      JFK       2
                      LGA       4
            7         EWR       4
```

When I shift this Series (test_series.shift(1)) I get

```
month  day  hour_dep  origin
1      1    5         LGA       NaN
            6         EWR       1.0
                      JFK       4.0
                      LGA       2.0
            7         EWR       4.0
```

What I want:

```
month  day  hour_dep  origin
1      1    5         LGA       NaN
            6         EWR       NaN
                      JFK       NaN
                      LGA       1.0
            7         EWR       4.0
```

I.e. shift all observations from previous hour to the next one.

Thanks for the help!

Some code to easily reproduce this data structure:

```
np.random.seed(2)
test_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 5, size=[2000,5]), columns=['Month', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Type', 'Test'])

test_series = test_df.groupby(['Month', 'Day', 'Hour', 'Type']).sum().head(10)['Test']

print(test_series)

print(test_series.shift(1)) # Observations in hour 1 do not correspond to the observations in hour 0. Observations in hour 0 should be NaN.
```